# How to handle readLine to terminate the read if line doesn't have terminated characcter?

Tags: bufferedreader, java-io

I am facing one strange problem where BufferedReader tries to read the line one by one using readLine() method but the data in the file is corrupted somehow and any particular line doesn't have terminated characters('\n' or '\r') so when it starts reading ,doesn't find the terminated character and after some time throws Out Of Memory error and stop whole application.

I just like to handle this scenario and when BufferedReader finds this scenario, it should terminate reading and complain about corrupted data and app should run thereafter. Does BufferedReader having some way to limit the length of the record so if it crosses the limit should terminate the reading.

Please advice me some good way to handling this with proper code example.

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. `BufferedReader.readLine()` reads lines. If your data isn't line-terminated, you can't use it: you will have to write your own input method.

Comment: That's not the case always but sometimes u get the corrupted data which doesn't have line terminated, so I have to identify somehow that this particular data has corrupted and doesn't allow to stop the application becoz it does other work as well.